# Put data from JSON file into local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, sapui5

I'm really new in working with SAPUI5 so I have to learn a lot in this topic. This is my current problem:

I have an application with input fields which have already values. These values are written into an JSON file. The app user can change these input values and should be able to save them using a save button. I've read that it isn't possible to change data in an JSON file by an user interaction. One should use local storage. How does it work? How can I put data from JSON file into this local storage?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: At some point your JSON file will be loaded into your application. From that moment on you are not working with the actual file anymore but with the data from that file represented as a JavaScript object. For more details about local storage usage in SAPUI5 see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

There is an API in SAPUI5 already called [jQuery.sap.storage](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.storage.html) and this is how you use it:

**Store Data**

```
var oStore = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);
oStore.put("id", { test: "test" });
```

**Retrieve Data**

```
var oStore = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);
var oDate = oStore.get("id");
```

The `put` and `get` methods already do the [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) (stringify/parse) work for you.

BR
Chris

Comment: Thank you! Can I store all data of my JSON file at once?

Comment: Sure you can. Just throw the whole object into the put method: oStore.put("id", oYourJSONData);

Comment: When I write oStore.put("id", "Assets") the system thinks that "Assets" is a value and not my JSON file. So I think something like this is better, isn't it? But it doesn't work, too.   jQuery.sap.require("jquery.sap.storage");  
   var oStorage = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local); 
   var oModel = new JSONModel(); 
   var oData = oModel.loadData("Assets");
   oStorage.put("LocalStorage", oData);  
   oStorage.get("LocalStorage");

Comment: This is confused. See below please

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of 'browser JS', local storage may be referring to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

To save json:

`window.localStorage.setItem('savedJson', yourJsonObject);`

To read:

`var loadedJson = window.localStorage.getItem('savedJson'):`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I tried what you said but there is an error: Local Storage must not be used in a Fiori application. I read something about jQuery.sap.storage but I don't know how to use it with JSON files. Have you or someone else any idea?